# Unity 5 collision still occuring

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm working on a 2D plane dodging game and I'm having issues in Unity 5, I'm trying to stop the collision between two incoming planes, I've tried many different solutions but those don't work. I can't put them in different layers because they still need to collide with the player. This is the code I have for the first plane. Enemy and Bullets are both tags. Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletPlane : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 6f;


    public float reloadTime = 1f;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject explosion;
    public GameObject smoke;
    public GameObject warning;
    public GameObject self;

    public float reloadSecond = .10f;


    private float elapsedTime = 0;
    public float timeElapsed = 0;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0, speed);
        Vector3 warningPos = transform.position;
        warningPos += new Vector3 (0, -10.5f, 0);
        Instantiate (warning, warningPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    void Update() {
        elapsedTime++;
            Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position;
            Vector3 secondPos = transform.position;
            elapsedTime = 0f;
            spawnPos += new Vector3 (0, -1.2f, 0);
            secondPos += new Vector3 (-1, -0.9f, 0);
            Instantiate (bulletPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            Instantiate (smoke, secondPos, Quaternion.identity);
            if (elapsedTime > reloadSecond) {
                spawnPos += new Vector3 (0, -1.2f, 0);
                secondPos += new Vector3 (-1, -0.9f, 0);
                Instantiate (bulletPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
                Instantiate (smoke, secondPos, Quaternion.identity);

                elapsedTime = 0f;
                timeElapsed++;
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player")) {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
        } else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Enemy")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (other.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), true);
        } else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Bullets")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (other.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the other enemy plane

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPlane : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = -6f;


    public float reloadTime = 1f;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject explosion;


    private float elapsedTime = 0;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0, speed);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Ally")) {

        } else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Enemy")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (other.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), true);
        } else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("BulletPlane")) {
            Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (other.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D> (), true);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2D. In this settings panel (at the bottom) you can set the layers to non-collide by default.

Comment: @Draco18s that doesn't work though because I still need them to collide with the player

Comment: ...That's what the collision grid is for...you can set the plane layer to not collide with *itself or any other layer you want* but still collide with the player layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still be able to set the layer, while your player can still be able to interact with.

Suppose you have 3 different objects

1. Plane A
2. Plane B
3. Player

and you want Plane A to don't collide with Plane B, but still collide with Player.

You can set the collision matrix on
Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2D

How to setup?

1. Set Plane A to Layer 'CollideOnlyWithPlayer'
2. Set Player to layer 'Player'
3. Then in the collision matrix, you can unchek all for layer CollideOnlyWithPlayer
4. But check for CollideWithPlayer to Player layer

The collision matrix define how object interact within the other object in layer.
It's defined by two indices, the vertical one and the horizontal one.
When you check for example, Vertical 'Player' to Horizontal 'Player'
this means, that your player can interact with player

And when you check for example, Vertical 'Player' to Horizontal 'CollideWithPlayer'
this means that your player physic can interact with object layered to CollideWithPlayer.

Pleas see the full documentation here
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: ok last question, I've made the extra layers that fit with each like player, enemy, and enemy bullet. I've labeled each appropriately with the enemies being spawned (Added the layer to the object being spawned) and checked off things like enemy/enemy, but their still colliding?

Comment: if you want to enemy not collide with enemy, then you have to uncheck enemy to enemy in the collision matrix.

Comment: I did, I even tried making a separate one for the different types of enemy's and unchecked them with each other and they're still colliding

Comment: Make sure you set the right collision matrix, there are 2 types of collision, 2D and 3D to set the 2D Collision matrix go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2D

And make sure that your object use the right layer.
if, you confident everything is fine, but still buggy, you can give me more detailed structure of your game and i will gladly to help

Comment: Also make sure you apply your layer to the object that has collider component in it